# Set WooCommerce product password via REST API

Tags: wordpress, rest, api, woocommerce

I am having some difficulty finding out whether it is possible to set the password-protected status of a product via the WooCommerce REST API.  In the documentation, it allows you to set product 'status', but does not list a protected option.

This is the field I am trying to set:

[image]

I thought perhaps this could be done by the Wordpress API (rather than the WooCommerce one), but would appreciate a bit of help as to how I would access the right product.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit your product the URL looks like this "/wp-admin/post.php?post=[id]&action=edit" where [id] is your product id.

The Wordpress REST API endpoint for this product is "/wp-json/wp/v2/product/[id]". With this endpoint you can change the password the same way as for Wordpress posts or pages.